# How to remove unwanted frameworks from xcode project

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I have some unused frameworks in my xcode project.I want to remove those frameworks from the project.
I tried deleting the framework but that deletes the framework from the entire xcode.Can anyone please tell me how to remove the framework only from the project not not the entire xcode

Comment: how you are deleting it?

Comment: remove reference use while delete...

Comment: " Click delete "

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply select the framework you want to delete in your list of frameworks in your Xcode project (which you see I've done on the left side of my Test project) and you should see this dialog when you click the "delete" key:

[image: delete confirmation]
Just click the *remove reference* button.

Do ***NOT*** click the "Move To Trash" button, or else you'll get the nasty surprise of losing frameworks out of your installed copy of Xcode.

Comment: The "Move To Trash" button shouldn't be able to actually move anything unless you're developing on an account with admin privileges; which is NOT a good idea (for this and other reasons).

Comment: Hi @geowar nice to see you here (!) -- You make a very very good point, but my guess is that most newer developers use accounts that have admin privileges by default.

Comment: Actually most older developers do also. And then are surprised when a customer runs their app on a non-admin account and things don't work as expected.

Comment: This was very helpful. Move to Trash will remove the framework from Xcode completely which I guess is not what anybody ever wants.

Comment: Will it be safe to remove the framework to trash if you're never ever going to use it again?

Comment: Yes @KarthikKannan, but read the above notes (especially from George Warner).  You need to be absolutely certain the framework you remove is not part of the macOS or iOS SDK that's built into Xcode.

Comment: Yup. I'm talking exclusively about 3rd party frameworks not the ones bundled with iOS. I should've made that more clear in my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In your Project

1) Go to Build phases.

2)Link Binary with libraries.

3)select your
    framework that you want to remove and press minus button down there.

Comment: Saved me from a problem of getting ride of unwanted frameworks that was previously implemented. Kept having complaints in build of looking for those removed frameworks but don't know how to update the link scripts until seeing your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your `Podfile` in your project and remove the pod you wish (e.g. Alamofire)
2. Go to project folder in Terminal. Enter `pod install` in the prompt.

It will remove frameworks which exist in your Project, but not in your Podfile.